# How to search double quote in developer tool's html viewer?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

[image]

The picture above shows the problem. You can't directly search double quote inside the HTML viewer in Chrome. So what is the proper way to search it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it could be achived with css selector (just add `[]` around `role="img"`)

```
[role="img"]
#map
```

Also by using XPath

```
//div[@role="img"]  - this would work in question case
//*[@id="map"]      - syntax example if you searching for id
```